# Numeric keypad for iOs with HTML5 not working for iPad

Tags: ios, html

I am developing an iOS app with HTML5. I am having a text box, which has to take only  numbers.  I have mentioned inputtype as number in HTML. But How can I get keypad only with number?

It works in android when inputtype is number, but not on ipad. (iOs version 10.3.1).

So need to know, how to force iOS to use Numeric keypad from HTML 5?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using

```
<input type='tel'/>
```